# Change date format from m/d/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, datetime-format

on one server [now.date()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.now.aspx) gives date like '08/06/2012 00:00:00' and on other gives '6/8/2012 12:00:00 AM'.
I need the date like '08/06/2012 00:00:00'. I can not use now.date.tostring("dd/MM/yyyy") as it is at too many places.
Can it will be achive by setting server date time formet?If yes then how.

Comment: Where have you found `now.date()` function?!

Comment: i am using this function. when i enter like string str=now.date().tostring("dd/MM/yyyy") it printing str gives like 15/06/2012

Comment: What is the full name and type of this function?

Comment: Public ReadOnly Property Now() As Date
     Member of: Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime
Summary:
Returns a Date value containing the current date and time according to your system.

Return Values:
Returns a Date value containing the current date and time according to your system.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend to set each server's datetime format to be the same in the system settings.

To override default format, you need to create your own CultureInfo with your custom datetime format, then set it as `Thread.Current.CurrentCulture`.

Comment: @Vikky: What exactly doesn't not affect what? Please be more specific.

Comment: on server date time it shows in dd/mm/yyyy format. I check in excel sheet on server too.it gives result in dd/mm/yyyy. But when i put now.date() on web page it return in m/d/yyyy format.

Comment: @Vikky: Use `System.DateTime.Now.ToString()` instead.

Comment: it is every where on site. i cant change it at once like this

Comment: @Vikky: You're using strange VB.NET-only helper utility instead of regular FCL call thus have strange behavior. Stop using it and you will get normal behavior.